# How to set TargetNullValue as folderpath in binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, targetnullvalue

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2"  Height="25"   IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Right"  Text="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups, TargetNullValue= 'C:\myfolder1\mysubfolder1',Path=DataContext.FoldernameWithPath,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"  Content="Browse"    Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   MinWidth="47"   Command="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups,Path=DataContext.OpenFolderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Before the user clicks the **browse** button,I need to bind the **Textbox** with default folderpath which is mentioned in **TargetNullValue**. But in my case it is binding like this **C:myfolder1mysubfolder1**

What I should do to bind the textbox like **C:\myfolder1\mysubfolder1** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the reason but adding another '\' seems to work:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2"  Height="25"   IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Right"  Text="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups, TargetNullValue= 'C:\\myfolder1\\mysubfolder1',Path=DataContext.FoldernameWithPath,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
<Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"  Content="Browse"    Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   MinWidth="47"   Command="{Binding ElementName=Mygroups,Path=DataContext.OpenFolderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: yeah...Thank you

Comment: The reason is that XAML strings are like normal C# strings.
The backslash is the [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/) of C# strings.
The most common one is ``\n``.
If one wants to print a backslash deliberately, he should do ``\\``, like in your solution!